# Singleton and Companion Objects are made how, are they instances?

Tags: scala

I have read how companion and singleton objects can be used to keep static methods, which makes sense. My question is how is this object made or instantiated it? I have read from some sources on how Objects are instances of the class if used as companion objects while others say they are not instances of the class. Then how are the objects existing or being made? Plus the Object would be same class data type I suppose?

Answer (score 3):

> My question is how is this object made or instantiated it?
>
> […]
>
> Then how are the objects existing or being made?

You don't know, shouldn't know, and can't know.

The Scala Language Specification says that they exist. The Scala Language Specification does not say how they are instantiated. Every implementor is free to implement them however they want.

For example, ECMAScript has object literals, so for Scala.js, there is no need for them to be an instance of any class at all. Scala-native is not dependent on any platform, so it can do whatever it wants. Scala-JVM needs to comply with the restrictions of the JVM, where every object needs to be an instance of a class. In Scala-JVM, every singleton object `Foo` is an instance of a JVM class named `Foo$`.

> Plus the Object would be same class data type I suppose?

The type of a singleton object `Foo` is the singleton type `Foo.type`. It's not a class.

> I have read from some sources on how Objects are instances of the class if used as companion objects while others say they are not instances of the class.

Instead of reading "some sources", it's much better to just read *the* source: [the Scala Language Specification](https://scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.13/), specifically [section 5.3.2 *Case Classes*](https://scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.13/05-classes-and-objects.html#case-classes):

> A case class definition of *[tps](ps<sub>1</sub>)…(ps)* with type parameters *tps* and value parameters *ps* implies the definition of a companion object, which serves as an extractor object. It has the following shape:
>
> ```scala
> object  {
>   def apply[tps](ps1)…(ps): [tps] = new [Ts](xs1)…(xs)
>   def unapply[tps](: [tps]) =
>     if (x eq null) scala.None
>     else scala.Some(.xs11,…,.xs1)
> }
> ```

Answer (score 2):

1. Each `object` has its own class, but you can't access the class directly. This class has a constructor without parameters which is called automatically when it's loaded and creates the only instance.
2. > Objects are instances of the class if used as companion objects

   Either you misunderstood or you really shouldn't trust these sources. It's possible for a companion object to extend the trait/class it's companion to, but not at all common.

Answer (score 0):

Companion objects are not instances of the class they're companion of, think of them more like a collection of utility methods. If you're familiar with Java - all the method, that you made `static` in Java (hence they don't belong to a particular instance, but to class in general) would go to Companion object in Scala. Also, companion objects have access to classes private values.

Objects are lazily initialized for you, you don't need to know when and how exactly are they created, just if you call a function from an object - it will be created for you, and there will be only one instance of it.